# Magento not executing my module install script

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am trying to create a local module. Here regarding this there are lot of question. I have almost all of them followed. But it is never working.

Atlast I followed this: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/magefordev/mage-for-dev-6.html

But this is als not working. Here is my structure:

app/code/local/Mycompany/Hello/Model/Resource/Setup.php

```
<?php
class Mycompany_Hello_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup {
```

}

in app/code/local/Mycompany/Hello/sql/mycompany_hello_setup/install-0.1.0.php

```
<?php
    echo 'Running This test: '.get_class($this)."\n <br /> \n";
    die("Exit for now");
```

app/code/local/Mycompany/Hello/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Hello>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mycompany_Hello>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <hello>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Mycompany_Hello</module>
                    <frontName>hello</frontName>
                </args>
            </hello>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <Mycompany_Hello_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mycompany_Hello</module>
                    <class>Mycompany_Hello_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </Mycomapny_Hello_setup> 
    </resources> 
</global>
```

Here the only issue I am facing is it never executes install script.
My approches till now:

Renamed app/code/local/Mycompany/Hello/sql/mycompany_hello_setup/install-0.1.0.php to following names on each attempt **app/code/local/Mycompany/Hello/sql/hello_setup/install-0.1.0.php**,
**app/code/local/Mycompany/Hello/sql/hello_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php**, **app/code/local/Mycompany/Hello/sql/mycompany_hello_setup/install-0.1.0.php**,
**app/code/local/Mycompany/Hello/sql/Mycompany_hello_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php**

During every attempt I flush cache and delete the entry from core_resources table.

All my file permisson is 777 (for debugging purpose, later I will change it to 755). Actaully I placed a debugging code in install. Once it executed, I will replace this with my actual installer script.

But it seems something, I am missing something, as a result it is not working.

Please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

in the `resources` tag, the first level node has to match the name of the folder inside sql/, and it is case sensitive.
So it should look like this:

```
    <resources>
        <mycompany_hello_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Mycompany_Hello</module>
                <class>Mycompany_Hello_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </mycompany_hello_setup>
    </resources>
```

And the setup script is in app/code/local/Mycompany/Hello/sql/mycompany_hello_setup/install-0.1.0.php
If it still doesn't work, check that there is no entry in the `core_resource` table with `code` = "mycompany_hello_setup" (delete it if there is one) and make sure that you have created the app/etc/modules/Mycompany_Hello.xml file, with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mycompany_Hello>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Mycompany_Hello>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it still doesn't work, check that there is no entry in the core_resource table ,delete it if there is one : This worked. 
As the table already had an entry of [module_name]_setup, I created new folder with the name [Namespace_name]_[module_name]_setup instead of deleting existing one and it worked.